# how to pass +, -, etc. to macro in Nim

Tags: macros, nim-lang

I want to do something like this macro in Nim

```c
#define BINARY_OP(op) \
    do { \
      double left = getLast(); \
      double right = getLast(); \
      push(right op left); \
    } while (false)
```

I tried to do this:

```
macro binaryOp(op: untyped) = 
  let right = getLast()
  let left = getLast()
  vm.push(left op right)
```

But the compiler throws an error:

```
Error: attempting to call routine: 'op'
```

How can I fix this?

### Update

I want to use the macro like this:

```
binaryop(+)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nim macros are not like C macros, they're code generators that take in source code. What you want is a template, which is akin to C macros, but still more sophisticated.

```
template binaryOp(op: untyped) = 
  let right = 10
  let left = 20
  echo op(left, right)

binaryOp(`+`)
```

In this case you need to use backticks to lexically strop `+`, explained [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#lexical-analysis-keywords-as-identifiers).

Comment: Sorry, I think I did not explain everything. Please read the update I added.